# "Pretending like a dog," "act like a dog," or "imitate like a dog"?

Tags: word-choice

> John looks his son, pretending like a dog.

> John looks his son, acting like a dog.

> John looks his son, imitating like a dog.

To make his son laugh, John acts/pretends/imitates like a dog.

Which one of the word is correct between *acts*, *pretends*, and *imitates*?

Comment: *John looks his son* is not grammatical and it's unclear whether you actually mean:  "John looks **at** his son pretending to be a dog" or "John **sees** his son pretending to be a dog".   In either case it's his son, not John that is acting like a dog.  Do you have other information that establishes that John is the one imitating a dog?  To involve his son and have John acting like a dog in the same sentence requires a completely different kind of sentence.  Like: "John gets his son to look at him by pretending to be a dog."

Comment: @Jim, is "John gets his son to look at him *imitating* a dog" correct? I think *imitating* there can be a valid usage of the present participle, instead in "by pretending" *pretending* is a noun.

Comment: @Carlo_R.- While not incorrect, I'd much prefer, "John gets his son to look at him by imitating a dog." or "by acting like a dog." any of those words can be used.  The problem with your suggestion is that it is slightly more ambiguous.  For example it could be used to describe the situation in which John says, "Hey son, look at this picture of me imitating a dog."

Comment: @Jim I'm confused. "John looks at Mike, acting like a dog." - Are you saying this sentence actually means Mike is the one who acts like a dog?

Comment: @T2E Technically with the comma in place it does allow the meaning to be John who is acting like a dog. However I don't know of any native speaker who would use that construction if it was indeed John who was being a dog because it is too easily misconstrued.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use any of them but the form of the sentence is somewhat different.

> John pretends to be a dog
>
> John acts like a dog
>
> John imitates a dog